# Manually colouring plots with `scale_fill_manual` in ggplot2 not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling with how to manually change bar colours in `ggplot2`. Strangely, I can get it to work when using more complicated formats that require a legend by using `scale_fill_manual` and setting the `values`,`labels`, etc. But when creating a simpler chart that doesn't require a legend, I can't seem to get it to work. Below is a sample data frame, the steps I used in `dplyr` to get the percentages, and how I think it should work in `ggplot2`. I just want to manually change the bar colours to red, seagreen3, and grey.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm also curious to know different ways that are used to quickly calculate percentages. I've been using piping with `dplyr`, but if would be great to see other ways of writing code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Service <- c("Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Neutral")
Service2 <- c("Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Satisfied")

Services <- data.frame(Service, Service2)

ServicesProp <- Services %>%
                select(Service) %>% group_by(Service) %>% 
                summarise(count=n()) %>%
                mutate(percent = count / sum(count))

ggplot(ServicesProp, aes(x = Service, y = percent)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "seagreen3", "grey"))
```

Comment: you have not mapped fill to any variable

Comment: NB! always make sure that the number of values/labels input to ```scale_fill_manual``` is the same as the number of classes your data has. Literally just wasted half a day staring at five lines of code not being able to understand where it was breaking.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just in case you are not sure what @baptise means:

```
ggplot(ServicesProp, aes(x = Service, y = percent, fill = Service)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "grey", "seagreen3"))
```

[image]